# Разница в условии, при объединении таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Надо выбрать продукты из нужной категории, есть 2 запроса, в одном есть условие AND, во втором WHERE, выборку делают одинаково, в чём разница?

```
SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id AND cat_name ='Овощи'

SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id WHERE cat_name = "Овощи"
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/211022/

Comment: используя именно **INNER JOIN** - в принципе разницы в данном случае нет

Comment: Запросы **АБСОЛЮТНО** эквивалентны. Неэквивалентны они лишь в случае стороннего либо полного внешнего связывания и "прыгающего" условия по таблице на подключаемой стороне

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category 
ON product.category_id = category.id 
AND cat_name ='Овощи'

ВЫБЕРИ все записи 
ИЗ product 
ДОПОЛНИ их записями из category
ОСТАВЬ из этой кучи такие, у которых поля product.category_id и category.id равны 
И среди которых есть cat_name = 'Овощи'
```

.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category 
ON product.category_id = category.id 
WHERE cat_name = "Овощи"

ВЫБЕРИ все записи 
ИЗ product 
ДОПОЛНИ их записями из category
ОСТАВЬ из этой кучи такие, у которых поля product.category_id и category.id
ПРИ УСЛОВИИ, что cat_name = 'Овощи'
```